# A simple program to accept only numbers

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple program to accept only numbers. but the program is accepting both letters and numbers

I'm using python 3.*.* I used the int data type in addition to input statement.

```
#A program to accept input of a number
print('Welcome to our age verification system.')
int(input('Enter your age: '))
```

I expected it to accept only integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can judge your input is a digit first.

```
#A program to accept input of a number
print('Welcome to our age verification system.')
input_string = input('Enter your age: ')
if input_string.isdigit():
    print(int(input_string))
else:
    print("please input a number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516093/python-how-to-only-accept-numbers-as-a-input)

```
try:
    int(input('Enter your age: '))
except ValueError:
    print('This isn\'t a number');
```

Comment: If it's a duplicate, just mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: I think you should escape the single quote. In the print statement: `print('This isn\'t a number');`