# I typed is digit function for user input, but when I enter an alphabet, it accepts the value

Tags: python

```
            IDcheck = input("Enter The Customer ID ")
            if IDcheck.isdigit :
                print("Your ID is Being Searched")

            elif IDcheck.isalpha :
                print("IDs Only Contains Numbers")
```

I made a code to search customers names by ID . typed isdigit function to make sure the user enters a number
but when I type a letter, it does accept it. why

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python how to only accept numbers as a input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516093/python-how-to-only-accept-numbers-as-a-input)

Comment: Those are _methods_. Call them.

Comment: `.()` is be of your help.... and check on unicode char inputs too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**String.isdigit is a function.**

When the interpreter executes the line `if IDcheck.isdigit:` it checks if a function or variable called `IDcheck.isdigit` exists. `IDcheck.isdigit` exist and it returns `True`. The same applies to `IDcheck.isalpha`.

To fix this: change `IDcheck.isdigit` and `IDcheck.isalpha` to `IDcheck.isdigit()` and `IDcheck.isalpha()` by adding parentheses, as in:

```
IDcheck = input("Enter The Customer ID ")
if IDcheck.isdigit():
    print("Your ID is Being Searched")

elif IDcheck.isalpha():
    print("IDs Only Contains Numbers")
```